# Is a double-level joins table possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I have three tables, `Show`, `Episode`, and `Character`. Each Show has_many Episodes and Characters.

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :episodes
  has_many :characters

class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
```

I have a list of Characters. What I want to do is order them by the date that their Show's second Episode aired on. Episode has a uniquely named attribute called `:air_date`

So I would have to do a two-level joins table, something like:

```
@characters = Character.joins(:show)
                       .joins(:episodes)
                       .where(episodes: {number: 2})
                       .order(:air_date)
```

But ActiveRecord thinks I'm looking for Episodes associated with Characters, and of course that association doesn't exist.

How can I return the Episodes associated with the Shows associated with a list of Characters? Or is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this syntax (I assume `air_date` is an attribute of `episodes`):

```
Character.joins(show: :episodes)
         .where(episodes: {number: 2})
         .order('episodes.air_date ASC')
```

You should also be able to use AREL for that:

```
Character.joins(show: :episodes)
         .where(episodes: {number: 2})
         .order(Episode.arel_table[:air_date].asc)
```

If you want to load everything to memory you can use `includes`, `preload` or `eager_load` instead of `joins`

A complete explanation and examples can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: I'm getting this error: `ArgumentError: Direction should be :asc or :desc`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong syntax in order. I fixed the answer. Please try again

Answer (score 0):

```
@character = Character.find x
@shows = @character.show.where(episodes: {number: 2}).order(:air_date).joins(:episodes)
```

Completely untested - I remembered an ActiveRecord query I saw some time back which put the joins at the end. It was a similar use case (get only the `x` records which met particular conditions).